# Trying to modify variables across other js file

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying not to make my js file so long and I want to split it up into different parts but keep updating the useState variables in the rest of the files.

```
//file1.js
import React from "react";
import {useState} from "react";
import form "./file2"

function file1(){

const [form1, set_form1] = useState(true);
const [data, set_data] = useState({Bas_size: null});
{form1 && form.form2}
}
```

```
//file2.js
import file1 from "./file1.js"

export const form2 = () => {
return(
<div>
    <form action="">
                    Base Size:{" "}
                    <input
                      type="number"
                      onChange={file1.set_data(Base_size:"10")}
                      name="Base_size"
                    ></input>
                  </form>
</div>  
);
};
```

I have tried everything but doesn't seem to work

Comment: File length is not a good reason to split a file. You do that for logical component hierarchy and separation of concerns (services, etc.). Then you pass state properties and functions to child components per [standard practice](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

Comment: If these files represent form components, state should be handled by an ancestor component or the app component and passed to each of them independently. They should not be interdependent. Also, I'd think you could create a reusable form component and just include that twice in your app.

Comment: Oops. Old docs above. Try this instead: https://react.dev/learn#components

Comment: Are you just asking how to render a custom component?  How to pass props to a component?  It's not really clear to me what your question is, but it looks like you should be starting with some introductory tutorials on React.